# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT error

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I have the following JSON, code and model:

#### This is the wire format of the JSON

```
{
  "success": "false",
  "http": "ok",
  "status_code": "200",
  "invoice_detail": {
    "notifications": [
      {
        "quantity": "414",
        "price": "5412",
        "total_price": "15748",
        "name": "Axel_Item_5412"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "414",
        "price": "5412",
        "total_price": "15748",
        "name": "Axel_Item_5412"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "414",
        "price": "5412",
        "total_price": "15748",
        "name": "Axel_Item_5412"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "414",
        "price": "5412",
        "total_price": "15748",
        "name": "Axel_Item_5412"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "414",
        "price": "5412",
        "total_price": "15748",
        "name": "Axel_Item_5412"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "414",
        "price": "5412",
        "total_price": "15748",
        "name": "Axel_Item_5412"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "414",
        "price": "5412",
        "total_price": "15748",
        "name": "Axel_Item_5412"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "414",
        "price": "5412",
        "total_price": "15748",
        "name": "Axel_Item_5412"
      }
    ]
  },
  "sgst": "125478122"
}
```

#### This is the retrofitCall method

```
private void retrofitCall() {
    String url= "http://www.amock.io/api/imran.cyber/get-fake";
    Call<ListModel> call= apiInterface.getList("", url);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ListModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListModel> call, Response<ListModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                String s= response.body().getInvoice_detail();
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+s);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ListModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

#### This is the model class

```
public class ListModel {

@SerializedName("invoice_detail")
public String invoice_detail;

public ListModel(String invoice_detail) {
    this.invoice_detail = invoice_detail;
}

public String getInvoice_detail() {
    return invoice_detail;
}

public void setInvoice_detail(String invoice_detail) {
    this.invoice_detail = invoice_detail;
}
```

And I get this error:

> 11-08 10:09:18.489 3578-3578/? E/MainActivity:: onFailure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 5 column 22 path $.invoice_detail

I'm unsure what is wrong: my JSON, my code or my model?

Comment: Why did not you try it?

Comment: You can check yourself: http://json.org/

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu  check it

Comment: but am not able to get **invoice_detail **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ListModel` you declare the field `String invoice_detail`, but in your JSON the `invoice_detail` is another object, not a String, thus you get that error message.

If you want to parse the JSON completely you have do define two more models to handle the invoices. The invoice detail containing the notifications:

```
public class InvoiceDetailModel {
    public InvoiceNotificationModel[] notifications;

    public InvoiceNotificationModel[] getNotifications() {
        return notifications;
    }
}
```

and a model for the notification itself:

```
public class InvoiceNotificationModel {
    public String quantity;
    public String price;
    public String total_price;
    public String name;

    // any getter methods here...
}
```

Then you can use `InvoiceDetailModel invoice_detail` instead of `String invoice_detail` in your `ListModel`.